# Jenkins and Docker

Tags: jenkins, containers, docker, jenkins-plugins

Is there a way to do automation with Jenkins to deploy and run containers? I heard we can use the Docker plugins for it. But there isn't any tutorials or info that explains how we can use Jenkins and Docker together. Anyone who uses them both care to share?

Comment: I think this is too large a question; could you instead try to do this yourself and ask a specific question if you get stuck?

Comment: The Jenkins plugins for Docker are primarily used to run Jenkins slaves. Is that your intention? If you intend using Jenkins to deploy containers might be simpler to simply create an SSH job that runs the docker command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off in my implementation of things Jenkins is actually a container in Docker.

Here's where it may seem things get bizarre:  I actually install docker-ce inside of that container, not because I want to run Docker-in-Docker.  I disable the Docker daemon from running (sysctl) but I want the command line.

I install docker-compose and docker-machine on the Jenkins host and add the "jenkins" userid to the docker group.

There's a bunch of other steps that I do but basically they are the same steps that a user is going to go through (except it's all in my Docker file) and I add the results of "docker-machine env" to the global variables in the Jenkins configuration.

head spinning yet?

Applications I have Jenkins deploying all have a "jenkins" subdirectory with a Jenkins file in it to perform the dirty work as a pipeline. (build/test/deploy)

Deployments for Java apps for instance involve copying the warfile for the application to the correct directory and when the container (or containers) start the application engine (tomcat, Jboss, whatever) picks it up and the application runs.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at
https://registry.hub.docker.com/search?q=jenkins&searchfield=

and at some Dockerfiles such as
https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/niaquinto/jenkins/dockerfile/

or 
https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/aespinosa/jenkins/dockerfile/